# Certainly not all shirts people have be part of some collection

Tags: infinitives, conjugations

Is it correct to say "all <somethings> be part of <something>"? The word "be" is sounding a bit wrong to me.

Comment: "all something" be "part of something" // definitely seems like an odd phrase. // "Children be good." is somewhat close. It means that all of children to who the statement is directed should be part of the collection of children who behave. // Let all of my bets be the right ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Certainly not all shirts *people have* **are** part of some collection.

The main sentence is

> Certainly not all shirts **are** part of some collection.

You cannot use an infinitive verb form (be) in place of a conjugated form (are).